# Proper setup of project.json for just .Net Core in RC2?

Tags: asp.net-core

With the release of .Net Core RC2 I have started rebuilding my website with it and after creating a web application I opened the `project.json` file so I could remove references to the older .Net versions but I am not sure which ones to leave in for just the .Net Core on a Windows IIS (Azure/Windows 2012R2). By default the file config looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

I know `dotnet5.6` is an older .Net (I think 4.6?). but what is the `portable-net45+win8`? Is that safe to remove? And do I need to change the imported tool to something else so it only imports tools for .Net Core and not 4.5/win8?

Comment: I wrote a blog post that you might find useful. https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/

Comment: @DavidPine Thanks but doing a quick look over that does not seem to be relevant. I am not doing a migration from RC1 to RC2. I am taking a .Net 4.6.1 site, putting it to the side, and rebuilding it from scratch in .Net Core. I also did not see anything talking about the tools or framework names in the post, did I miss something that would help answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project json looks good. If you do not add any further packages, you can remove the complete "imports" node below the netcoreapp from your project.json. It just states, that if a depending package can also target "dotnet5.6" (or "dnxcore50" or "portable-net45+win8" instead of "netcoreapp1.0". It is bascially a statement allowing the brand-new netstandard and netcoreapp targets to use NuGet packages which are not yet migrated to netstandard. The ASP.NET Core assemblies have already been migrated.

Comment: What about the `imports` in the `Tools` section? Is that needed as well?

Comment: Just to verify: Can the project be run natively (without mono) on Linux, with the imports `dotnet5.6`, `dnxcore50` and `portable-net45+win8`?

Comment: @Matthew Honestly, I think you cannot spare that in the tools. Have not tried. Just try it. Wont compile without it.

Comment: @rmac the word natively is dangerous. Since above project.json has a "portable" reference, it needs .NET Core installed (it is a so-called "portable app". There is a mode called self-contained, which is nothing else than smart packaging of the same stuff. Further, the term "native" is close to .NET Native (alpha) which means that it is even ahead-of-time compiled and not delivered as bytecode.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the clarification. The distinction I was after was if the imports made the app rely on Mono or not.

Comment: Yes it will run w/o Mono but with either a shared pre-installed .NET Core or a bundled .NET Core

Comment: @Thomas It builds when you remove it but I don't know what the implcations of it are or if there is a tool I should import specific for .net core 1

Comment: @Matthew: The project.json is gone once you have it compiled. The import statement helps NuGet to extract the right assembly fitting to your app.